# Is it possible to use Directfb to play .mp4 and .avi?

Tags: video, directfb

Is it possible to use Directfb to play .mp4 and .avi?
I know the Directfb can play GIF. So can it play video such as .mp4 and .avi? How?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can play AVI file for sure, I'm not sure if mp4 can be played or not.

To do this:
While compiling directfb use  `--enable-avifile` (you need to have compiled avifile library - http://avifile.sourceforge.net/)

Then you can use .avi files in your program, see http://directfb.org/downloads/Extras/DirectFB-examples-1.7.0.tar.gz
Download examples from above link and see df_video.c to use it.

Comment: I tried to install avifile library like you suggested but didn't success.
Can you share how you install it?


Also find this link http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/multimedia/avifile.html but maybe the problem is my system. 
My machine is Ubuntu 12.04 32bit.